# List of English words with usage samples

Tags: corpora, dictionary, resource-request

For my learning tool project I need a free English word list with the usage sample of each word and/or its definition.

For example:

```
/word/ Apple
/phrase/ This apples are big and red.
/definition/ Apple is a fruit of the apple tree.
```

Could you please tell me, where can I get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the English wiktionary (https://en.wiktionary.org) as a free resource.